# Fill Series, a lot of Series's?

Tags: vba, excel

In Excel I've got sequential box numbers in column B, and each box has a couple dozen files that need sequential-by-box place numbers in column C.  The way I usually do this is to Fill Series down a selection (selected by hand) of all the cells for that box in Column C, which is fine if you've got a few boxes to do, but now I have several hundred.

[I've got a 394x290 example screenshot I was going to include to show what I mean, but since this is my first post I don't have enough rep, sorry -- [link to it on g+ here.]](https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/-Ryilrmy9TEA/U2hcfXfxhLI/AAAAAAAAAMY/AHZkzOZ4YyY/w493-h363-no/screenshot.05-05-201415.22.54.jpg)

I thought I could put some VBA code into a macro to select the contiguous cells with the same box number, offset one column right [Offset (0, 1), yeah?], fill series those cells from 1, and go on to the next box.  But I haven't had any luck finding anything similar that's been done, nor have I been able to get anything I've looked up to work for this.  (Not surprising since I rarely try VBA, hopefully my question's not too noobish for this site.)

Comment: re screenshot: use a file sharing service and post a link.

Answer (score 0):

From what I can tell, you want the **Plc** column to fill up series starting from 1 for the same **Box Num**.

There may exist a fast and quick way but simple method is to go through the rows. Try below:

```
Sub FillUpPlc()
    Dim oRng As Range, n As Long ' n used for series filling

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    n = 1
    Set oRng = Range("B2")
    Do Until IsEmpty(oRng)
        ' Increment n if it's same as cell above, otherwise reset to 1
        If oRng.Value = oRng.Offset(-1, 0).Value Then
            n = n + 1
        Else
            n = 1
        End If
        oRng.Offset(0, 1).Value = n  ' Store n to next column
        Set oRng = oRng.Offset(1, 0) ' Move to next row
    Loop
    Set oRng = Nothing
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: This worked beautifully (and quickly, barely took 20 seconds), thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

No need to break out the VBA. This can be done with a formula. Starting in C2 and copied down

```
=IF(B2<>B1,1,C1+1)
```

Much, much faster than VBA looping through thousands of rows.

Comment: The VBA looping didn't take very long (and I'm glad to have working code so I can see what I was doing wrong), but your solution is more elegant than I knew to ask for -- thanks!

Comment: Cool @teylyn! I wasn't thinking clearly... @kickair8p you can combine VBA with teylyn's formula so you don't have to drag fill the series!

Comment: You don't need VBA to avoid drag-filling the formula, either. Just double click the fill handle. That's what it's there for. It fills the formula to the last cell in the recognized range. If column B has no blank rows, put the formula into C2, double click the fill handle and - BOOM!. You'll hardly have time to inhale an exhale. Compare that to "barely took 20 seconds".

Comment: C'mon, lets not fight -- they're both beautiful solutions and I'm very happy with both of 'em.  Thanks again!

Comment: I didn't mean to fight. Sorry if that came across that way. I'm very passionate about using the out of the box features before even thinking about code. On a site like this I see a lot of solutions that use pages and pages of code, where a simple tick in a box would do the same thing. People just don't know enough about how powerful Excel already is, even without VBA.  Fascinating, really. Enjoy.